# where is this newcommand syntax going wrong?

Tags: macros, errors

This is a part of questionnaire where `\details` are to be repeated after every question. I tried to define it using `\newcommand`. Where am I going wrong. Please test on http://www.overleaf.com as you may not have relevant font .

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{titling}
\setmainlanguage{hindi}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}
\setmainfont{Lohit Devanagari}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\devanagarifont}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\devanagarifont}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\devanagarifont}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{12}{14.4}\devanagarifont}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{9}{10.8}\itshape}
\newcommand{\details }{\begin{itemize} \item कब से है ?\dotfill \item क्या दवाये चल रही है ?\dotfill \end{itemize}}
\title{क्या आपको निम्न लिखित बीमारियों में से कुछ है ? }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\selectlanguage{hindi}
\begin{enumerate}
\item मधुमेह (शक्कर की बीमारी) : \dotfill
\details
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is the error you get `! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.25     \end{document}`

Comment: @ David Carlisle yes. Exactly. I think I will have to change title to English

Answer (score 4):

The error is apparently

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

removing as much as possible while still generating the error shows that the font used is not related to the issue

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

   \usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} 
   \usepackage{titling}

    \title{ttt}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

`scrartcl` has its own mechanisms for controlling the format of titles and frontmatter, it is probably best not to use generic packages that are mainly designed to customise classes based on the standard `article` class for that purpose when using this class.

If you have a specific formatting requirement and want to know how to address that with the koma classes that's a different question really (that most likely someone more familiar with `scrartcl` than I am would answer)

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying this code has worked, though I  do not know what was wrong. This is not the actual answer,  but a working solution

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hindi}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Devanagari}
\setmainfont{Lohit Devanagari}
\newcommand{\details }{\begin{itemize} \item कब से है ?\item क्या दवाये चल रही है ? \end{itemize} }
\title{क्या आपको निम्न लिखित बीमारियों में से कुछ है ? }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\protect
\selectlanguage{hindi} 
\begin{enumerate}
\item मधुमेह (शक्कर की बी मारी) : \dotfill 
\details 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```